# How to drag formulas down every night at midnight?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know little to nothing about code so please bear with me. I am just wondering if it is possible to use google scripts to automatically pull down formulas every night at midnight so I don't have to. I have looked online and don't yet have the knowledge to adapt various ideas to my task. Here is what I need, as best I can describe at the moment:

In sheet (this sheet) start at cell C33 and go down until you identify the last value in that continuous range of data. This is equivalent to hitting control+downarrow. Then from that bottom-most cell, for instance, C191, identify the last value to the right (equivalent to hitting control+rightarrow). So now your range is C191:Z191. Once you have identified that range, drag it down. I am dragging down formulas and I want them to stay as formulas, not be pasted as values.

I just want it to run automatically every night at midnight if possible. That's it except for 1 pretty annoying exception. On the first day of the month still drag everything down as normally but do NOT drag down the second cell to the right (which would be in column E). So for instance, you would then drag down C191:D191 and F191:Z191

Sorry for basically asking for a complete answer, but I figured I may as well before spending however many weeks learning the requesit skills to understand and write this script.

Comment: Look into the various discussions on using the arrayformula function to apply a formula to an entire row.  This is a built in function and will accomplish what you want real time as opposed to only at midnight.  There are some quarks, but it is very powerful.  An example might be: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,M1:M + N1:N + J1:J))`

Comment: Karl, I was unaware of this functionality. It's very cool. There are some definite things I'm needing to figure out a solution for but it looks promising so far.

Comment: Sounds good.  Not that the sample I copied was actually a part of a larger version which was placed in the header row.  As I have it here, if the cell is in row 1, it places the Header text. This keeps it out of all the data rows: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A) = 1, "Total Fees", IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),,M1:M + N1:N + J1:J)))`  Also note that since there is no value for the TRUE in the IF statement the cell will be empty.  Had a used '' or "" then an empty string would be placed there.  This is different than Excel and confuses many.

Comment: Can you identify why this works
=ARRAYFORMULA(If(A2:A<$B$2,C2:C-E2:E,""))
but this doesn't 
=ARRAYFORMULA(If(and(A2:A<$B$2,A2:A<>""),C2:C-E2:E,""))

the former will expand but when A becomes ="" then zeros will be returned. I don't want that, as shown in my second formula. But my second formula returns nothing at all. Why is this?

Comment: the AND works on an Array, I believe, and will basically return a single result.  There are some functions which do not work inside the arrayformula  sum() is another.  For your use, nest IF statements so when one is true the next one is checked. If I have this correct it becomes `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<$B$2, IF(A2:A<>"" ,C2:C-E2:E,)))`  Note that I dropped your "" to keep empty cells.  I would probably also use ISBLANK to test for an empty cell:  `=ARRAYFORMULA(If(ISBLANK(A2:A),, IF(A2:A<$B$2,C2:C-E2:E,)))`

Comment: Interesting. Yes it appears both of those work, I think the second it slightly easier to understand. I suppose this method will work. Now it's a question of how much this will effect the calculation time on our docs which are already slow enough. And also: is the added confusion worth the time savings.

Comment: Well I've decided I can rule this option out on the basis that you are unable to see the formula unless you click on the first cell. That hadn't occurred to me until now. Due to our system we hide the top cells (unavoidable) but need to be able to see the formulas quickly and easily if an error arises. So this would be un ideal. Awesome though, I'll use this some time in the future I'm sure

Comment: If want to boost your calculation speed by a lot you might want to use sheet.getDataRange() and create an array of the entire sheet run through the array doing the calculation and then copy the array right back onto the sheet.  I usually get an order of magnitude difference in performance this way.  Of course, the down side is that your calculations are often buried loops, indices and not so human readable script.

Comment: Try this in the header row.  With it you can access the formula and hide from row 2 down as far as you want. `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A) = 1, "HEADER TITLE",If(ISBLANK(A2:A),, IF(A2:A<$B$2,C2:C-E2:E,))))`

Comment: Karl, that's an interesting approach, it might work. Do you have any idea what this is only populating some cells and not others even though all the data seems to check out?
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A33:A406) = 33, "# Articles Launched",If(ISBLANK(H33:H406),, IF(value(H33:H406)<value(A$32),F33:F406-G33:G406,))))

I will troubleshoot later, just thought I'd ask if there is anything obviously wrong. The values I am testing against A32 are dates with A32 being today and the rest being previous dates. The only cells filling with results are clustered around the 1st of each month.